# About the following code in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am reading a piece of code as follows,

```
 u = account.generate_user
    {
      id: u.id,
      name: u.name
    }
```

Could you let me know what does the above snippet does? Does it do the following?

```
 u = account.generate_user
 account.id = u.id
 account.name = u.name
```

Is there any reference to this usage?

Comment: I think the hash is the return value of the method

Comment: The indentation is quite misleading. The hash looks like an argument.

Comment: also thought it's an argument to `generate_user` first

Comment: Could you provide a litte more context? What comes before and after the code piece?

Comment: This is whitespace abuse. In this case, `{...}` is an options hash, not a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first generate an object (`u`), and then return a hash, with values being method calls on that object.

> Does it do the following?
>
> `u = account.generate_user`
>      `account.id = u.id`
>      `account.name = u.name`

Nope. In the  hash you are not accessing `account`'s attributes/methods (`id` and `name`), but of the newly created object `u`.

What is `u` depends on `account.generate_user` return value.